# Unable to start MapReduce task.Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster

Tags: xml, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginner in Hadoop, and I tried to use MR to import some data into HBase but failed. The console shows the error information:

```
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster
```

[Here is the screenshot of the whole error log page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BShW9.png)

I found some solutions by google and stackoverflow, most solutions said it is related to the configuration of mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml, however, I found nothing wrong with mine. Is something wrong with mapreduce.application.classpath?

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>   
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
                <value>master:10020</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
                <value>master:19888</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
                <value>
                    /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*,
                    /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
                </value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.app-submisson.cross-platform</name>>
                <value>true</value>>
            </property>>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>master:8032</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
            <value>master:8030</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>master:8031</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
            <value>master:8033</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
            <value>master:8088</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
            <value>
                /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*,
                /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
            </value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are these properties available in all slave nodes and in the client node where the job is submitted?

Comment: Yes, of course. Already applied to both the Namenode and 2 Datanodes.

Comment: Not sure whether this would solve, can you try setting the variable `HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME` in the environment if not set already

Comment: No, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The classpath should be delimited by colon (:) instead of comma (,), modify your `mapreduce.application.classpath` and `yarn.application.classpath` to be like `/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:...` and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: `yarn.application.classpath`: CLASSPATH for YARN applications. A comma-separated list of CLASSPATH entries. Refer [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)